# Convert each CSV file record into separate JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, json, csv

I want to convert.CSV file record (EACH record) into JSON file. I've tried this code, 
but it's giving me full file conversion into JSON, not separate file for each record.

```
 string[] cols;
            string[] rows;
            int cnt;
            long unixSeconds = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            string desti = destination + unixSeconds.ToString();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourceFile);  //SOURCEFILE
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(desti);  //DESTINATIONFILE
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        cols = Regex.Split(line, ",");

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(cols[i], typeof(string));
        }
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            table.Rows.Clear();

            int i;

            string row = string.Empty;
            rows = Regex.Split(line, ",");
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();

            for (i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = rows[i];
                cnt = i;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
            sw.Write(json);
        }
        sw.Close();
        sr.Close();
```

Actual output

```
[  {
    "Temprature": "30"
  }]
[
{"Temprature": "30"  }]
```

Expected Output only one record

```
[  {    "Temprature": "30"
  }
]
```

Comment: You will have to loop through your `table` array and json encode every entry seperatley

Comment: not working need to close sw.Close();
            sr.Close();

Comment: Luchspeter is right: If you only have a single sw, yu will only get one file.
Throw away sw, find an algorithm to generate a new filename with every loop and do a `File.WriteAllText( filename, json )` instead of `sw.Write(json)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your destination file is always the same for each record so `sw` writes json in the same file .you need to give diffrent destination file name for each record.

2.If you are trying to give different file name using `destination+DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` then it gives same name (the process is very fast and it completes within a millisecond) and it only shows last record (it did not even append record also) .you need to use `Guid.NewGuid()` to create a different name or any other technique.

```
        string[] cols;
        string[] rows;
        int cnt;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourceFile);  //SOURCEFILE

        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        cols = Regex.Split(line, ",");

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(cols[i], typeof(string));
        }
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            table.Rows.Clear();

            int i;

            string row = string.Empty;
            rows = Regex.Split(line, ",");
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();

            for (i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = rows[i];
                cnt = i;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
            string desti = destination + Guid.NewGuid(); //Destination file
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(desti);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
            sw.Write(json);
            sw.Close();
        }

        sr.Close();
```